Remove the hide-keyboard button when iOS keyboard is open
In XCode, is there a way to remove the "hide-keyboard" button ? I'm trying to prevent the keyboard from hiding when the hide-keyboard button is tapped and can only be hidden when the done button is tapped.
The only options i found for the textfield and keyboard are:
fullnameTextfield.keyboardType
fullnameTextfield.keyboardAppearance
fullnameTextfield.keyboardLayoutGuide

None of these have any options for hiding a specific button on the keyboard.


What does "In Xcode" mean? Don't you mean "on iPad"?

I'm almost sure you cannot hide it, the button is a part of keyboard. It's more about you who has to develop iPad apps the way so keyboard may disappear any second during user's interaction with the app - let's say enabling hardware keyboard

Even Apple's legacy "archived" documentation had very little to say about iPad keyboard, but the short answer is:

no.

The software keyboard in iPad is also different, because in the landscape orientation, the form factor of the keyboard covers a lot of the screen, and often it will actually cover the insertion point of a text field that is in a non-scrollable view.
Also, the iPad keyboard has received extra features over time, like Split, Undock, and Floating, and they appear in a menu when you long press this button.
An iPad developer should work extra hard to make sure that the insertion point is never covered by the soft keyboard, but realistically, I think Apple's choice to be conservative by always providing the "hide keyboard" button is sound.

Is there a way to disable the action of hiding the keyboard when its pressed at least?

I'm imagining that you could mess around with the responder chain... but likely it would cause the soft keyboard to dismiss and then re-display? That would have an animated bouncing-effect... which might be good or bad, depending on the user's perspective.

It's not possible.
When the keyboard is open, you can't directly remove it through standard public APIs because it's part of the default iOS keyboard behaviour. However, you can use a custom keyboard if you want full control over the layout and appearance of the keyboard.
